# Isekai anime where the boy MC reached 100th reincarnation in the 1st episode

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

I got to episode 1. The anime was an isekai, the main character was a boy and he reached his 100th reincarnation/life in the 1st episode (in his 1st life he lived on Earth - Japan - in our world, and after that he reincarnated in many other worlds).

His mother is a concubine, and his father is the ruler (I don't remember if he is king or emperor, but the king is more likely), so he is an illegitimate child who will not inherit anything, this was also mentioned in the anime, his mother regretted that how he will have to live. And the main character was happy despite everything, because he just wants to rest in this life. Her hair was grey-white/white/light grey, his mother too.

At the end of the episode, he did some mana-strengthening magic he had learned in his previous lives, he was a baby so it was very difficult. This spell was some sort of qi or chi or something that if I remember correctly amplifies his mana. He learned this in one of his previous lives. At the very end of the episode, he let out a loud cry because he had exerted himself so much (the maid left the room just then)

Comment: [Otome Game Sekai wa Mob ni Kibishii Sekai desu](https://isekai.fandom.com/wiki/Otome_Game_Sekai_wa_Mob_ni_Kibishii_Sekai_desu#TV_Anime)?

Answer (score 1):

"[How a Former Pro Takes Advantage by Doing an Easy Job](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/w9w1a61/the-sweet-life-of-a-reincarnation-pro)". I think it is this one:

> Arel may have been born as a prince of the Ernesia Kingdom, but this is actually his 101st life! He has been reborn into multiple types of universes that were full of magic, qi, and even spaceships. So this isn't his first fantasy world, and he's going to make use of his magic knowledge to take it easy. His past 100 lives have taught him that the best way to avoid dying young is to keep his head down and make lots of money. But let's see if this reincarnation pro can finally live the sweet life.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an anime. It's a webcomic and webnovel.